# Format date column pandas

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I wan't to change the format of a date column in pandas. In my example called `df_transactions['date']`.

The format I am aiming for is `format='%d-%m-%Y'`. However my code, doesn't seem to work.

This is the code I tried:

```
df_transactions['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df_transactions['date'], format='%d-%m-%Y')
```

Not sure if it's important information but I did a check on the datatype and it says: `dtype: datetime64[ns, pytz.FixedOffset(60)`

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: What is the problem with the code? to_datetime transforms into a datetime

Comment: [pd.to_datetime](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) returns a datetimeindex, whereas a formated date is a string. The 'format' argument of to_datetime helps you parse datetime from a string. If you want to get a string at the end, you should use [df_transactions.dt.strftime](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.strftime.html) (after converting using to_datetime)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do something like this:

```
import pandas as pd

# dummy data (assuming the date column is a string)
rng = pd.date_range(pd.Timestamp("2018-03-10 09:00"), periods=3, freq='s')
df_transactions = pd.DataFrame()
df_transactions['date'] = rng.astype('string')


# transform to datetime and format with strftime
df_transactions['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df_transactions['date']).dt.strftime('%d-%m-%Y')
print(df_transactions)
```

**Output**

```
         date
0  10-03-2018
1  10-03-2018
2  10-03-2018
```

See the documentation on [strftime](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.strftime.html) for more information.  Note that if the column is already a something like a DatetimeIndex, you don't need to use [to_datetime](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html#pandas.to_datetime).

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try:

`df_transactions['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df_transactions['date'])`

and then do this:

`df_transactions['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df_transactions['date'].dt.strftime(format='%d-%m-%Y'))`

Comment: This basically the same as my answer

Comment: yes, they are the same